# Send Email using Power Automate and attached a file from folder in my pc to the email

Tags: excel, email, attachment, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have excel files in folder in my pc and i want to use Power Automate tool to attached them in email and send them automatically to selected recipients

I saw some tutorials, but all of them read from SharePoint and not from folder in pc

Comment: ... and your issue is?

Comment: I'm not able to create automated email that read from file .. i am afraid that there is no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

From you tags I see you are using Power Automate Desktop? In that case your issue should be pretty straightforward: Use the "Get files in folder" action and from that you can get the path of each of your Excel files (provided that they are all in the same folder, if not you'll probably have to repeat this step depending on how many folders you have to work with). The path can be reached by adding the prefix ".FullName" at the end of your variable name and you can then use that in your "Attachments" field for a "Send Exchange email" action.

On the other hand, if you are using Power Automate Cloud, similar logic applies; but not to write all the steps - lemme just Google that for you.
https://www.powertechtips.com/attach-files-to-email-power-automate/